# Some JavaScript background worker concerns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have 2 questions.

1. On some WordPress themes, they apply JQuery effects only on the
   visible contents. For example, 3 div blocks in bottom of the page
   are hidden at the beginning and fade in slowly when I scroll to the
   bottom. What technique they used or what event they catch whenever
   the content is visible?
2. I saw some websites having multiple slideshows, text scrolling...
   How can they run so many tasks at once? To my way of thinking, they
   must assign the tasks to many background worker. Each worker have
   different timer to take care of the effects. Am I right? I asked
   this question because based on what I read, JavaScript is single
   threaded so running multiple tasks is not possible.

I'm not trying to do something with WordPress, just want to know how they can do that so I can try to rebuild it and apply to my own project.

Comment: You have to create two question if you ask about two different topics.

Comment: I think they are related so I put them together. :) Sorry if it is not a good way to ask.

Comment: Those are completely different topics. Question one is, how to catch if content is/becomes visible or not. Second question is, how to create code so that multiple tasks run _simultaneously_ in a single threaded environment.